# Working cmake/mingw configuration stopped working. The C compiler is not able to compile a simple test program

Tags: c, windows, cmake, mingw, clion

I write the C program using MinGW on windows 10 with Clion IDE. I had everything working and compiled successfully multiple times before. Can't link the error with any action but now cmake test in Clion fails - "Test Cmake run finished with errors" and I can't compile. Cmake error:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/karol/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/193.6015.37/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: C:/Users/karol/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build11621595605978509144/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe cmTC_15aad/fast && C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_15aad.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_15aad.dir/build
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/karol/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build11621595605978509144/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_15aad.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_15aad.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c C:\Users\karol\AppData\Local\Temp\cmake_check_environment\_build11621595605978509144\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_15aad.exe
    C:\Users\karol\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\193.6015.37\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\cmTC_15aad.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
    C:\Users\karol\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\193.6015.37\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -E remove -f CMakeFiles\cmTC_15aad.dir/objects.a
    C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\cmTC_15aad.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\cmTC_15aad.dir\objects1.rsp
    C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe      -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\cmTC_15aad.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o cmTC_15aad.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libcmTC_15aad.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\cmTC_15aad.dir\linklibs.rsp
    gcc.exe: fatal error: cannot execute 'ld': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\cmTC_15aad.dir\build.make:88: cmTC_15aad.exe] Error 1
    mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/karol/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build11621595605978509144/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:120: cmTC_15aad/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/karol/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build11621595605978509144/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/karol/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build11621595605978509144/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Error code: 1
```

I don't know what caused it. One thing I did around the time it broke is turn off avast cyber capture. But now I turned off avast antivirus completely and turned off "Check apps and files" option in Defender. The latter I did when Clion popped a notification saying "Windows Defender might be interrupting build speed". I also clicked "fix" in this Clion pop-up and it added project folders to exceptions. Clion notified me of it not immediately after the error but way later.

The directory "C:/Users/karol/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/" mentioned in the error report doesn't exist. I tried unchecking "read-only access" of AppData/Local/temp directory but Windows keeps putting it on. Between those changes and antivirus changes, I was restarting windows many times.

The error message i get when trying to compile:

```
C:\Users\karol\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\193.6015.37\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\karol\Desktop\studia\wstep_do_C\final_project\cmake-build-debug --target final_project -- -j 2
[ 20%] Linking C executable final_project.exe
gcc.exe: fatal error: cannot execute 'ld': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\final_project.dir\build.make:134: final_project.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/final_project.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/final_project.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: final_project] Error 2
```

Many poeple experienced simmilar error caused by non-latin characters in path, not the case here. Also i don't suspect mingw installation as it used to work.

[Clion toolchains settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/651ap.png)

Comment: It's claiming that it can't find your linker `ld`.  Check the `%PATH%` variable.  Most build systems have feature that lets you dial up the logging, such that it includes the environment variables prior to executing any process(es).  Find your `ld` command and then make sure it can be found at build time.

Comment: I've added C:\msys64\mingw64;C:\msys64;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin; to Path. It is there at build time. But i couldn't find "ld" command anywhere in MinGw files, i have only found ld.gold in Mingw64/bin directory.  What should i do?

Comment: Reinstall Mingw?  I seem to recall that on many *nix systems, `ld` is just an alias for the system linker.  Your problem might be that your build environment is missing an alias named `ld` that should be pointing to a specific linker.  I don't know the GNU tool chain or Mingw well enough to give more specific advice than that.

Comment: thanks for the answers, i will just switch for linux for now as I need to have it done by the end of semester.

Comment: I've seen antivirus / malware tools remove portions of buildtools as being unsafe.  Maybe avast quarantined the linker.